# Contar milisegundos en Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript

En *ActionScript 3*  me gustaría contar los milisegundos de la diferencia entre presionar dos botones.

Ejemplo:

```
boton1.onClick{
  $inicio = now (PHP);
}

boton2.onClick{
  $fin = now (PHP);
}

$milisegundos = $fin - $inicio;
```

Para mostrar el resultado puedo usar:

- `echo $milisegundos;`
- `salida.Text = milisegundos;`

Comment: Amig@s, hace 5 años hice unas pruebas en Actionscript 2:


En el frame: 

milisec = getTimer();

En el botón 1: 

on (keyPress "<Left>"){
 msecstart = milisec;
}

En el botón 2:

on (keyPress "<Right>"){
 msecstop = milisec - msecstart;
 trace (msecstop);
}

Así de sencillo ando buscando algo para AS3.

Saludos y cualquier dato se agradece